# Indirectly calling CoInitializeSecurity from a .NET application

Tags: .net, c, com

I have the following code in a pure C project:

```
void Foo()
{
    HRESULT hres =  CoInitializeEx(0, COINIT_MULTITHREADED); 

    hres =  CoInitializeSecurity(
        NULL, 
        -1,                          // COM authentication
        NULL,                        // Authentication services
        NULL,                        // Reserved
        RPC_C_AUTHN_LEVEL_DEFAULT,   // Default authentication 
        RPC_C_IMP_LEVEL_IMPERSONATE, // Default Impersonation  
        NULL,                        // Authentication info
        EOAC_NONE,                   // Additional capabilities 
        NULL                         // Reserved
    );
}
```

If I build the project as an Application (.exe) and invoke this method, everything works fine.

If I build the project as a Static Library (.lib), use it in a .NET application and invoke the method, CoInitializeSecurity returns a error 1008: An attempt was made to reference a token that does not exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [expected behavior](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/98268/no-way-to-set-com-security-level-cannot-call-coinitializesecurity-in-2-0) in that [`CoInitializeSecurity`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/library/ms693736.aspx) is not meant to be called from code executed within the CLR.

If you have an explicit need to call `CoInitializeSecurity`, then you need to [host the CLR yourself](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163567.aspx) and call `CoInitializeSecurity` before the CLR is started in the process.

Comment: Does the same apply to CoSetProxyBlanket ?

Comment: @FranciscoSilva: Yes, both `CoInitializeSecurity` and [`CoSetProxyBlanket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa910618.aspx) are listed as ["problematic" to call from within the CLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385973(v=vs.90).aspx).